# How to map case and category while import articles in lightning knowledge using article import

Tags: lightning-experience, knowledge, data-import, lightning-knowledge

In classic there are multiple article types. I have taken backup and need to import them again to lightning knowledge using article import tool. I am able to import articles using csv file and property file. Coming to rich text fields I have created html file.

Do I need to create as many html files if my csv file contain thousands of records for rich text fields??

How to map which case the article is attached and which category the article belongs during import articles into knowledge using article import tool??

Answer (score 0):

When preparing articles for import, if you want to import the body of the article in rich text, then you do need to convert the body of each article to a separate HTML file.  This means that if you're importing **100 articles**, you would have **1 CSV** file that lists all the articles & **100 HTML** files (which contain the rich text content for each article).

To map categories to your articles, add a column to your CSV for each category & use the column name of **datacategorygroup.INTERNAL_NAME_OF_CATEGORY**. For more information, review the page [Create a .csv File for Article Import](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_article_importer_02csv.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Its really useful to me. How about case mapping to the article, because we have standard field 'ArticleCaseAttachCount' in article type.